# Regex if/else Statement?

Tags: regex

My current pattern looks like this: `(line:\s*)+([A-z,0-9;.]+)`

which normally works great, to match the word after every 'line:'.

[image]

But I've found some special cases in my test string, where it doesn't work right.

[image]

It doesn't match the strings starting with '--', which is also right, but instead of matching nothing, it should match the next String who matches no matter how many strings before start with '--'.

Is there a way to add an if/else Statement like: if string starts with '--' then match next string.

Or is there any other solution?

Comment: Please don't spam unrelated tags. If you are really using [tag:nsregularexpression] and/or [tag:qregularexpression] please [edit] to clarify; but I'll remove them both for now.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Regarding, "if string starts with '--' then match next string", what is the start and end of a "string"? Whenever you encounter whitespace I'm guessing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ignore white spaces AND substrings start with `--`, try

```
(line:(?:\s|--.*)*)([A-z,0-9;.]+)
```

The only difference is `(?:\s|--.*)*`.

Not only it captures white spaces `\s`, it also captures comments `--.*`.

See the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/Z29tjB/1)